# WebSQL Cannot read property of undefined

Tags: jquery, html, sql, database

```
db.transaction(function (tx) {
  tx.executeSql(
    "SELECT COUNT(*) as id FROM offline_post WHERE link=? and author=? and title=?", 
    [link, create, title], 
    function (tx, results) {
      alert(results.rows[0].id);
    }
  ); 
});
```

> Cannot read property 'id' of undefined

**SOLVED**

I solved the problem in this way :)

```
 db.transaction(function(tx) {
    tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM offline_post', [], function(tx, results) {
        //resolve the promise passing the count data
   alert(results.rows.length);
    });
});
```

Comment: That's a very bad approach, you're selecting all the rows just to get their count. Not to mention you are no longer filtering the posts...